# How to make an interdepending form input with props in vue?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, model

i want to build a reusable form component like

`<buy-form :price="price" />`
(which would make the price pre-set and readonly. i want to be able to pass any of the three fields' value `amount`, `price` and `total`

inside the form, there are 3 vuetify `v-text-field` s.

`BuyForm.vue`

```
<template>
<v-card>
    <v-card-text>
      <crypto-input :value.sync="form.amount" :disabled="!!amount" label="Amount"/>
      <crypto-input :value.sync="form.price" :disabled="!!price" label="Price"/>
      <crypto-input :value.sync="form.total" :disabled="!!total" label="Total"/>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-spacer />
      <v-btn depressed dark :color="style">BUY</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
</template>

<script>
  import styles from '@/styles/_export.scss'
  import CryptoInput from './CryptoInput'

  export default {
    name: 'BuyForm',
    components: { CryptoInput },
    props: {
      label: {
        type: String,
        default: null,
      },
      price: {
        default: null,
      },
      amount: {
        default: null,
      },
      total: {
        default: null,
      }
    },
    data: () => ({
      form: {
        amount: null,
        price: null,
        total: null,
      },
      styles,
    }),
    mounted() {
      Object.keys(this.form).forEach((e) => {
        this.form[e] = this.$props[e]
      })
    },
// ...
```

so far, so good. changes in the inputs reflect in the `data.form` object.

now of course i want to calculate the remaining field (i.e. i pass `price`, so users can input amount or total, and the other one will be calculated.)
so i set up a watcher for each field, but here's the problem:
those watchers fire all the time, because if users input `amount`, `total` is changed automatically, so `total` watcher fires, which in turn calculated again and so on.
in most (?) cases, this is fine, because the value will be the same.
but i've encountered some edge cases, where it breaks (clearing one field for example).
i've tried to start fighting all these problems with a gigantic mess of watcher logic

```
watch: {
      'form.amount': function(newVal) {
        if (!this.$props.amount) { // not disabled
          let { amount, price, total } = this.form
          if (this.$props.price) this.form.total = amount * price
          if (this.$props.amount) this.form.price = total / amount
        }
      },
      'form.total': function(newVal) {
        if (!this.$props.total) { // not disabled
          let { amount, price, total } = this.form
          if (this.$props.price) this.form.amount = total / price
          if (this.$props.amount) this.form.price = total / amount
        }
```

and that's just the very basic idea, nowhere near "working" or even "good".

looking forward, the case where none of the field is disabled gives me headaches, because three fields will depend on each other, and each one will fire its watcher on being changed, and i'll have to be prepared for all that....

of course this feels super wrong. so my question is: is there a best practice to do this? this can't be the only way to do it? am i missing something obvious? is there maybe even a library that can be bent to do this task? i didn't find any, and i don't want to spend hours on this abomination just to end up with a super brittle and bloated mess.

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the details of how your version of `value.sync` works so **im gonna pretend that you are using regular `v-model`** (with `value` prop and `input` event to propagate changes).

To trigger recalculation only on user input, instead of using watchers you should trigger them in on-change listeners, for example.:

```html
<input
  :value="form.amount"
  @input="onAmountChange"
/>
```

```js
methods: {
  onAmountChange (value) {
    this.form.amount = value;
    ... // recalculation logic
  }
}
```

Or even go one step further to make your template cleaner, and do it using computed properties

```html
<input v-model="formAmount"/>
```

```js
computed: {
  formAmount: {
    get () {
      return this.form.amount
    },
    set (value) {
      this.form.amount = value;
      ... // recalculation logic
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, i'm passing `value` and emitting `change` events. gonna try it your way, looks like it will probably work better than mine. it's just pretty hard to wrap my head around passing props over 3 levels, while keeping them in sync and calculating interdependent values... i'll let you know if i got it to work like this :)

Comment: That's true, this can be a pain in the ass. For this reason many people uses (read till the end) [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), which **i myself consider an anti-pattern** (because it's very easy to lose track of which component edits what), but i feel obligated to state that it is widely used (it's not a bad library, it's just often misused). I prefer [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kamilbeben/1e8fd0p6/36/) approach. It's basically making use of vue mixin, vue model-property and javascript's proxy.